# Error with function call within async function in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have general function to check true or false value.

i have called that function with parameter.

```
export const isSelectedOrgEDU = (companyCode, employeeId) => {
  if (companyCode === "702" && employeeId === "23534084") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

in loading-screen i have make a function call.

```
const getRequiredAPIDataInStore = async () => {
    GetAllFieldProp();
    GetAllSalaryAPIResponse();
    isSelectedOrgEDU("702", "23534084")
      ? GetAllSpecificSalaryAPIResponse(true)
      : GetAllSpecificSalaryAPIResponse(false);
}
```

But i am getting error from this.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: (0, _generalHelperFn.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _generalHelperFn.default)("702", "23534084")', '(0, _generalHelperFn.default)' is undefined)]
```

How can i solve this error?

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with import statement

Comment: no its correct imported.
import isSelectedOrgEDU from "../helpers/general-helper-fn";

Comment: It should be `import { isSelectedOrgEDU } from "../helpers/general-helper-fn";`